# shuffle linked list in Swift

Tags: swift, data-structures

I am studying data structure in Swift. I have a question, so I ask. In a normal array, you can shuffle the array using a function called'shuffle()'. However, I am not sure how to mix the data in the Linked list. While thinking, I post a question like this.

1. This is node setting code

   ```
   public class Node<T> { 
       public var value: T 
       public var next: Node<T>? 
       public var previous: Node<T>? 
       public init(value: T) {
           self.value = value
       }
   }
   ```

I would appreciate any advice or any material I can refer to!

Comment: it depends on your requirement. If it's just shuffle value in the list, you can simply do it with O(n) complexity.
Let loop from head to tail to create an array of values. Shuffle the array, then loop again to assign new values to the list.

Comment: Thank you nghiahoang, Can I find examples of algorithms or source code? I can't understand exactly what you said.

Answer (score 0):

```
var node = yourNode
var array: [Int] = []         // in case T is Int
while let n = node {
    array.append(n.value)
    node = n.next
}

array.shuffle()

var node = yourNode
var i = 0
while let n = node {
    n.value = array[i]
    node = n.next
    i += 1
}
```